# MySQL: Count the distinct rows per day

Tags: mysql, sql, time, count

I have an interesting query I need to do. I have a table with an `INT` column containing ip address numbers (using `INET_ATON`), and a `timestamp` column. I want to be able to count the number of unique ip address columns there are per day. That is, how many distinct ip rows there are in each day. So, for example, if an ip address is in the same day twice, it counts as 1 in the final count, however if the same ip address is in another day it'll be counted there will be a second count for it.

#### Example Data:

```
PK | FK  | ipNum      | timestamp
11 | 404 | 219395     | 2013-01-06 22:23:56
7  | 404 | 467719     | 2013-01-06 22:23:41
8  | 404 | 4718869    | 2013-01-06 22:23:42
10 | 404 | 16777224   | 2013-01-06 22:23:56
5  | 404 | 1292435475 | 2013-01-06 22:23:25
12 | 404 | 1526990605 | 2013-01-06 22:23:57
6  | 404 | 1594313225 | 2013-01-06 22:23:40
4  | 404 | 1610613001 | 2013-01-06 22:23:23
9  | 404 | 1628635192 | 2013-01-06 22:23:55
1  | 404 | 2130706433 | 2013-01-06 21:29:38
2  | 407 | 2130706433 | 2013-01-06 21:31:59
3  | 407 | 2130706433 | 2013-01-06 21:32:22
```

Comment: can you give sample data (even atleast one) fro timestamp column?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
SELECT  DATE(timestamp) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT ipNum) totalCOunt
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY  DATE(timestamp)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11aa6/1)

Comment: This will produce multiple rows for each day. Could I then somehow add together all the rows for the totalCount column?

Comment: Links are dead now

Comment: links still work for me, you just have to select the correct DB type at the top of the screen and rebuild

Comment: Downvoted as the answer is on a different site, linked only from a comment, with no commentary here on what the answer might have been if that site goes away.

Answer (score 8):

Here's how you'd get counts per day for the last 7 days:

```sql
select
    count(*) as count,
    date(timestamp) as date
from
    tablename
where
    timestamp >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day)
group by 
    date;

+-------------+------------+
| count       | date       |
+-------------+------------+
| #forThatDay | 2020-02-21 |
| #forThatDay | 2020-02-22 |
| #forThatDay | 2020-02-22 |
| #forThatDay | 2020-02-23 |
| #forThatDay | 2020-02-24 |
| #forThatDay | 2020-02-25 |
| #forThatDay | 2020-02-26 |
+-------------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

group by the `ipNum` column first to get distinct counts of that column per day:

```sql
select
    count(*) as count,
    date(timestamp) as date
from
    tablename
where
    timestamp >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 7 day)
group by 
    ipNum, date;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$log_date     = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$log_date     = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($log_date.' -1 hour'));
SELECT ipNum, COUNT(ipNum), COUNT(DISTINCT ipNum), DATE(timestamp), timestamp FROM tableName  WHERE `timestamp` > '".$log_date."' GROUP BY ipNum ORDER BY DATE(timestamp) DESC
```

THIS WILL GIVE YOU A RESULT LIKE

```
 ip                  TIME               COUNTIPS
11.237.115.30     2018-01-27 19:13:51       1
21.744.133.52     2018-01-27 19:14:03       1
44.628.197.51     2018-01-27 19:48:12       14
```

Comment: I would recommend reading on how MySQL handles [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: If you test your query, you will not receive the desired result. You are requesting `timestamp` as well as `DATE()`

Comment: this code works for hourly results ,also count (ips) in 1 row and that worked for me, unlike many other solutions I read and did not work.
 
if you encountered an error (unless I accidentally put the "select" unnecessary commands), the following works perfectly SELECT visitor_ip, COUNT (DISTINCT visitor_ip), DATE (date_added), date_added, ip_id FROM ". $ cam_ip_table." WHERE `date_added`> ''. $ Log_date. '' GROUP BY visitor_ip ORDER BY DATE (date_added) DESC

I'd be happy to tell me what you would correct in my code to improve in the future.

thank you

Comment: Please put together some sample data on SQL Fiddle and show that it works.