# MySQL: Count the distinct rows per day including 0

Tags: mysql, distinct

Thereis a good answer to the main question here: [MySQL: Count the distinct rows per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191021/mysql-count-the-distinct-rows-per-day/25825358#25825358)

I need it with the days with values also included but the query

```
SELECT  DATE(timestamp) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT ipNum) totalCOunt
FROM    tableName
WHERE totalCOunt < 1
GROUP   BY  DATE(timestamp)
```

gives an error ( #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE  totalCOunt < 1
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3 ). Where did I go wrong?

Sample data here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11aa6/146

Comment: Could you please add some sample data in http://sqlfiddle.com along with the expected output in the question.

Comment: SELECT  DATE(timestamp) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT ipNum) totalCOunt
FROM    tableName

GROUP   BY  DATE(timestamp) HAVING totalCOunt < 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is throwing Unknown column 'totalCOunt' in 'where clause' error:

Please try the below query(**replaced WHERE clause with HAVING clause**):

```
SELECT  DATE(timestamp) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT ipNum) totalCOunt
FROM    tableName

GROUP   BY  DATE(timestamp)
HAVING totalCOunt<1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors:

1. `Date` should be escaped, as it is a keyword in MySQL.
2. The syntax is wrong. You forgot `AS`.

So the corrected one is:

```
SELECT  CAST(`timestamp` AS Date) AS `Date`, COUNT(DISTINCT(`ipNum`)) AS totalCOunt
FROM    `tableName`
GROUP   BY CAST(`timestamp` AS Date)
```

#### Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/809838/8

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an alias in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT  DATE(timestamp) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT ipNum) totalCOunt
FROM    tableName
WHERE totalCOunt < 1
GROUP   BY  DATE(timestamp)
```

Use HAVING instead:

```
SELECT  DATE(timestamp) Date, COUNT(DISTINCT ipNum) totalCOunt
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY  DATE(timestamp)
HAVING totalCOunt =1
```